# AUTOIT alternate software\

Tags: software-center

Is there any equivalent software to autoIT is available for ubuntu?

I cant able to upload the files using selenium webdriver without autoIT.

autoIT software only supports in windows.

thanks in advance....

Comment: when in doubt.. http://alternativeto.net/software/autoit/?platform=linux